# Concatenate numbers from nested cells into date strings

Tags: date, multidimensional-array, concatenation, cell, octave

I have a cell array with cells as in

```
sCell =
    {
      [1,1] =
      {
        [1,1] = 2020
        [1,2] = 03
        [1,3] = 04
      }

      [1,2] =
      {
        [1,1] = 2020
        [1,2] = 03
        [1,3] = 05
      }

      [1,3] =
      {
        [1,1] = 2020
        [1,2] = 03
        [1,3] = 06
      }

      ...
    }
```

And I want

```
[1,1] = 2020-03-06
[1,2] = 2020-03-05
```

etc.

I tried addressing with curly braces but did not succeed without using for.. endfor.

This functions but I want to get rid of the for loop:

````
```
for jj=1:3; 
sd(1,jj)=strcat(sCell{jj}{1,1},'-',sCell{jj}{1,2},'-',sCell{jj}{1,3}); 
endfor 
```
````

Is there a faster/compacter way?

Comment: Please don 't add information in comments, rather [edit] the question with everything you've tried. Cells are notoriously inconvenient, you'll have to loop over this. Should be easy though, if all your cells look the same. Also MATLAB at least has [`datenum`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) etc functions which handle dates much easier than what you propose.

Comment: Again: don't add information in comments, ***[edit]*** the question please. Either press the link on [edit] in this comment, or the [edit] button beneath the tags on your question.

Answer (score 1):

A more compat way:

```
A = reshape([[sCell{:}]{:}], 3, []).';
A = [A zeros(size(A))]
result = cellstr(datestr(A, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
```

The operator `[cell{:}]` can be used to convert an array of cells to an array of the contents of the cells. Apply the operator twice to convert nested cells to a vector of numbers.
Use `reshape` and `transpose` to form a `[m x 3]` matrix of numbers and append to it three columns of zeros so it can be used as the matrix of date vectors in [`datestr`](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Timing-Utilities.html#XREFdatestr). Finally use [`cellstr`](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Cell-Arrays-of-Strings.html#XREFcellstr) to form cell array of date strings.